# Given $\mathcal{F}$ a filter on $X$, and either $A$ or its complement are in $\mathcal{F}$, then $\mathcal{F}$ is ultrafilter

Tags: elementary-set-theory, filters

I am trying to prove the following fact:

> Given $\mathcal{F}$ a filter on $X$, Suppose $\forall A \subseteq X$
>   where  either $A$ or $X\backslash A$ are in $\mathcal{F}$, then
>   $\mathcal{F}$ is ultrafilter

We know that

> $\mathcal{F}$ is an ultrafilter if for all $F$ a filter on $X$,
>   $\mathcal{F} \not\subset F$

How to proceed with this question?

I'm stuck at first step trying a contradiction proof.

Suppose $\forall A \subseteq X$ where  either $A$ or $X\backslash A$ are in $\mathcal{F}$,  then let $F$ be another filter on $X$, we will show that $F\subset \mathcal{F}$. Proceed by contradiction, suppose that instead $\mathcal{F}\subset F$, we will show that this is not the case...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose by contradiction that we have some filter $F$ such that $\mathcal F \subsetneq F$. Pick some $A \in F \setminus \mathcal F$.
Now, $A$ is not in $\mathcal F$ so by hypthesis $X \setminus A \in \mathcal F$ and since $\mathcal F \subsetneq F$ also $X \setminus A \in F$.

But then both $A, X\setminus A \in F$ so their intersection which is the empty set is also in $F$ which contradicts the definition of a filter.

Comment: Fucking Brilliant